# Reading a textfile and splitter on delimiter

Tags: c#, split, text-parsing

I have a textfile with the format:

> FieldName1: value\t
>
> FieldName2: value\t
>
> FieldName3: \t
>
> FieldName4: value\t
>
> FieldName5:
>
> value   value  value   value
> value   value  value   value
> value   value  value   value
> value   value  value   value
> \t
>
> FieldName6: value\t

Field values have the delimiter '\t' to identify the end of a field definition. In the example, there are two special cases: an empty value and a value that spans across multiple lines.

Is there a way to read in a textfile and split each element by the delimiter '\t'? I've tried playing around with File.ReadAllLines(filePath) and it just splits the file line by line.

Comment: `string[] fields = File.ReadAllText(filePath).Split('\t');`

Comment: Does the file only contain one record with 6 fields?

Comment: How do you represent a data value of '\t' in your file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the text in the file with the delimiter \t like this:

```
string [] fileds = File.ReadAllText(filePath).Split("\\t");
```

Same as the answer above, bu you need to escape the \t .